# Custom add to cart button to add multiple product into cart with price. woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Whether it is possible to add when pressing the custom button at the same time two and more goods to cart (for example on goods id), at the same time to give a discount of 5%, or to set own price to these goods (as a last resort to apply the coupon created in advance)?